# PHP adding different images for every 5 items in a loop

Tags: php

I have several articals I am storing in my database and I have 5 different images I want to show in a foreach loop.
Basically I want to show image2 in every second, seventh, twelfth and so on...

```
<div id="1">
    image1
</div>
<div id="2">
    image2
</div>
<div id="3">
    image3
</div>
<div id="4">
    image4
</div>
<div id="5">
    image5
</div>
<div id="6">
    image1
</div>
<div id="7">
    image2
</div>
```

Something like :

```
if ($i == 2 || $i == 7 || $i == 12 || $i == 17 || $i == 22 || $i == 27 )....
```

Comment: try this logic `if(($i - 2) % 5 == 0){ .... }`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show the image on seventh record, it only shows on second record

Comment: Why don't it? Check the given example i posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another options would be to use `array_chunk`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Assuming your articles are stored as `$articles` you could do something like:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($articles, 5);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {

    foreach ($chunk as $key => $article) {

        ?>

        <div>
            Use Image <?php echo $key + 1 ?>
        </div>

        <?php

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Using the given logic you can optimize your Condition to the desired number--

```
for($i = 2 ; $i < 100; $i+=5){
    if(($i - 2) % 5 == 0){
        echo 'This is: '. $i.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
This is: 2
This is: 7
This is: 12
This is: 17
This is: 22
...........
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/6MvZR)